# gdb backtrace - show inlined functions, like `addr2line -i` does

Tags: c++, gdb, backtrace, addr2line

I have gdb attached to process. I print backtrace, one of frames looks like this:

```
#9  0x000055b748d7467b in CA::CryptUserKeysCache::addSongKeyFast (this=0x55b74e141a90, group_color=..., timePeriodValidUnit=timePeriodValidUnit@entry=366, keyIsValidFromTime=1573653252507218,
    useSystemValues=useSystemValues@entry=false) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1307
```

That is my function, but definitely not my file. I expect this is due to inlining. Is there a command that will show me how this inlining proceeded? Something akin to `addr2line -i`?

For comparison, addr2line with slightly different backtrace, but close.

`addr2line` plain:

```
CA::CCryptSongPrivateGroupMgrKey::JoinMyselfToGroup(Borg::AbstractGroupHash const&) at /usr/local/linux64-hard-2.17/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:987
CA::CryptUserKeysCache::addSongKeyFast(Borg::AbstractGroupHash const&, unsigned short, long, bool) at /home2/mateuszl/git/borg-engine/core_inter_headers/core_separate_libs/libs/crypto_types/src/CryptUserKeysCache.cpp:1699
```

with `-i`:

```
CA::CCryptSongPrivateGroupMgrKey::JoinMyselfToGroup(Borg::AbstractGroupHash const&) at /usr/local/linux64-hard-2.17/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:987
 (inlined by) ?? at /usr/local/linux64-hard-2.17/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:1073
 (inlined by) ?? at /usr/local/linux64-hard-2.17/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:45
 (inlined by) ?? at /home2/mateuszl/git/borg-engine/core_inter_headers/core_separate_libs/libs/uint128/src/../include/borg/uint128/uint128.h:50
 (inlined by) CA::CCryptSongPrivateGroupMgrKey::JoinMyselfToGroup(Borg::AbstractGroupHash const&) at /home2/mateuszl/git/borg-engine/core_inter_headers/core_separate_libs/libs/crypto_song/src/CCryptSongPrivateGroupMgrKey.cpp:234
CA::CryptUserKeysCache::addSongKeyFast(Borg::AbstractGroupHash const&, unsigned short, long, bool) at /home2/mateuszl/git/borg-engine/core_inter_headers/core_separate_libs/libs/crypto_types/src/CryptUserKeysCache.cpp:1699
```